# SSRS: expression to split string into specific lengths

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, substring

I'm trying to write an SSRS expression that will split a string in order to fill a text box correctly.

My current approach is to create 3 substrings (one for each line) which are each the length of the line and then place a newline after each substring.

**Current expression:**

```
=Left(Fields!fullShippingName.Value, 49) + vbCRLF 
 + Mid(Fields!fullShippingName.Value, 50, 108) + vbCRLF 
 + Mid(Fields!fullShippingName.Value, 109)
```

**Raw Data:**

```
UN1760, Waste Corrosive liquids, n.o.s.   8, III (nitric acid, hydrochloric acid) (RQ: D002,D004,D006,D011)
```

**Current result:**

[image]

Currently, the second and third lines are not returning the desired result length.

**Expected Result:**

[image]

**ANSWER:**

```
=Left(Replace(Fields!fullShippingName.Value, Chr(10), " "), 49) + vbCRLF
 + Mid(Replace(Fields!fullShippingName.Value, Chr(10), " "), 50, 108) 
 + vbCRLF + Mid(Replace(Fields!fullShippingName.Value, Chr(10), " "), 109, 167)
```

Comment: Instead of Chr(10) try using vbCRLF. Also, shouldn't the second Mid function take 3 parameters?

Comment: For the second Mid function, my intention was to start at 151 and get everything else afterward.

Comment: Can you show your string as raw data and show your expected result?

Comment: Is there a Chr(10) or Chr(13) in the data? That would cause the wrapping. Try Replacing those values with a space.

Comment: There was Chr(10) in the data and when I replaced those it worked. Thank you and I posted the answer in my question.